# How to interact with a MySQL database using winJS?

Tags: mysql, html, winjs

I just started with Win 8 apps and I need to create an app that interacts with a MySQL database. I think I will go with the HTML5 & WinJavascript way but I have not seen a way about how to do it.

Can somebody give me some example using queries like `select`, `insert` and `delete` on WinJS?

I know some Javascript and HTML, and the lifecycle of a Win app. I tried to search for answers on how to connect to a database but I could not find anything.

Comment: Unless you have a WinRT compatible library for communicating with MySQL, you can't directly perform queries. You'll need a middle-tier server (like a web server with web services) to perform the operations on behalf of your application.

Answer (score 0):

WinJs is Javascript.

You can use Ajax to call webservice that will perform your queries.
Or if you don't have too big of a database I recommend you use Azure Mobile Services for storing your data. It's very well integrated with WinJs and it make it easy to work with.